# IcCube table with dimension header

Tags: iccube-reporting

When I am trying to show a few measures over a dimension (e.g. revenue per category) in a simple table, I am not able to add the dimension name to the table. It always looks like this:

```
|     |revenue|clicks|
| 1234|   3.48|    5 |
| 5678| 100   | 1000 |
```

Is there a way, to show the result like this:

```
|category_id|revenue|clicks|
|       1234|   3.48|    5 |
|       5678| 100   | 1000 |
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no option to display the name of the dimension in the table header. Nevertheless, for your example you could use the "Corner Text" option to display "Category ID".

Here is an example adding the "Years" dimension:
[image]